# HTTP protocol association in Universal app

Tags: uwp

I want to implement an efficient text based, script-less web browser for Windows 10 mobile; intended for low RAM devices where Edge crashes constantly. I want to associate the HTTP protocol to the app so that I can open links (from email, Cortana search result, ...) with it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to implement is protocol activation. You can use the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching/README.md) as entrypoint to get started. It comes down to 3 steps:

1. Add a protocol activation declaration to your manifest.

[image]

2. Add the correct icons as this will be shown in the launcher and default apps.

> We recommend that you include the proper icons with your project so that your logo looks great in all of these places. Match the look of the app tile logo and use your app's background color rather than making the icon transparent. Have the logo extend to the edge without padding it. Test your icons on white backgrounds.

3. Handle the activated event

Code:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;

        // TODO: Handle URI activation
        // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri
    }
}
```